# Initializing an int array as a type argument

Tags: c++, arrays

This code fails to compile:

```
  unordered_map<char, int[4]> inv = {
    { 'a', {{0,0,1,0}} } 
  }
```

What's the proper way to initialize this int array when passed as a type argument?

I've tried: `int[]`, `array<int,4>` but they all give the error:

```
no instance of constructor "std::unordered_map<_Kty, _Ty, _Hasher,
_Keyeq, _Alloc>::unordered_map [with _Kty=char, _Ty=std::pair<Cell *, int []>, _Hasher=std::hash<char>, _Keyeq=std::equal_to<char>,
 _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const char, std::pair<Cell *, int []>>>]" matches the argument list
```

Comment: This code should complain that unordered_map is undefined. Post actual code that fails to compile.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: ??? Should user provide the needed header files? Is this now common in SO?

Comment: @Klaus The user should provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Klaus he is hiding a using std; so what `unordered_map` is he using? He may have implemented his own :)

Comment: @Klaus considering OP's comments to accepted answer it seems that defect was in a #include being missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
#include <array>

std::unordered_map<char, std::array<int, 4>> inv = {{ 'a', {{0, 0, 1, 0}} }};
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Works for me with `clang 7` and `gcc 8`.

Comment: Actually include <array> fixed it, threw me off because the error was the same as when I used int[]

Comment: @lubgr can you explain why `int[4]` doesn't work but `std::array<int, 4>` does? Just curious :)

Comment: @LarsNielsen `std::unordered_map<char, int[4]> myMap;` will compile, but any insertion will fail to compile, because you can't assign to an existing `int[4]` array, e.g. `myMap['a'] = {1, 2, 3, 4};` gives you something like "int[4] is not assignable". Same as `int test[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};` (which works)  and then `test = {5, 6, 7, 8}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize the array with one set of angle brackets.

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<char,std::array<int,4>> inv = {{ 'a', {1,2,3,4} }};

    for (auto &&i : inv)
        std::cout<< i.first << "->" <<i.second[0] <<std::endl;
}
```

Example: https://rextester.com/FOVMLC70132